# How to Send email using Sendgrid?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid-api-v3

How to send mail using Sendgrid, i had tried many time but give error,
Error like class not found,i  had  also install composer but i cant understand, please give me solution 
ERROR IMAGE:[image]

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
include_once('credentials.php');
$FROM_EMAIL = 'from@gmail.com';
$TO_EMAIL = 'to@gmail.com';
$subject = "test";
$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, $FROM_EMAIL);
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $TO_EMAIL);
$htmlContent = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body><p>hi this is test</p></body></html>';
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html",$htmlContent);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
$sg = new \SendGrid($API_KEY);
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
if ($response->statusCode() == 202) 
{
    echo 'done';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, you have to prefix `SendGrid\Email` with a backslash `\` :

```php
$from = new \SendGrid\Email(null, $FROM_EMAIL);
$to = new \SendGrid\Email(null, $TO_EMAIL);
```

---

For more details, it has been discuss in `sendgrid-php` issues 
 https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/341

Comment: which backslash @nenroz ?

Comment: Did you install `sendgrid` with composer ? https://packagist.org/packages/sendgrid/sendgrid